# Extract plot datapoints from a diurnal plot generated using R openair timevariation function

Tags: r, subset, subplot, openair

*I have used the following code and extracted the data for the "hour" subplot from the tibble. However, I have forgotten how to do it now. I am not sure if I am missing any code at the bottom. Please modify the below and let me know how to get the data in CSV or text format.
*

**

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(openair)
library(dplyr)

Georgia <- read_excel("C:/Users/TT/Desktop/FT/AA/Daily Average/Georgia.xlsx", 
                   sheet = "Refined Data", col_types = c("text", 
                                                         "text", "date", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                         "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                                         "numeric", "text", "numeric", "text", 
                                                         "text", "text"))

tail(timeVariation(selectByDate(Georgia, year = 2017), pollutant = "pm2.5", group = "month"), subset ="hour")
```

**

[The tibble I need to extract :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vppD5.png)

Comment: 1: Don't include library calls to unnecessary packages, especially when they can cause a big mess like tidyverse. 2: Text, especially code, is usually best presented as text, not as an image. 3: Make a [mcve]. `dput()` can come in handy

Answer (score 0):

The `openair` package comes with test data. Here is an example on how to extract the data for the hour plot.

Here we create a `tv` object which is the result of `timeVariation` function using the example data:

```
library(openair)

tv <- timeVariation(mydata, pollutant = "nox")
```

To access the plotted data including mean and confidence intervals, you can then use:

```
tv$data$hour
```

Or, to store in a .csv file, try (include filename of interest):

```
write.csv(tv$data$hour, "openair_mydata.csv")
```